# pjax making multiple requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pjax

When calling pjax in Chrome (version 21) javascript console, I see two requests in my development log.  I tried changing the timeout as was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153263/jquery-pjax-request-sending-twice), but I still get two requests.  Any ideas?

```
$.pjax({timeout: 4000,
      container: '[data-pjax-container]',
      url: document.location.href });
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I wasn't rendering the application template, which returned nothing in the http body.  Consequently, the pjax code it caused the request to fallback to a standard GET.

Why wasn't I rendering the application template? Well, I'm a dummy and was using this method in my application controller

```
def get_layout
  request.xhr? || request.headers['X-PJAX'] ? nil : 'application'
end
```

The problem here is that I'm using `content_for` in my index.html.haml.

```
- content_for :sub_nav do
 # view code
- content_for :main do
 # view code
```

My application.html.haml template looked like this...

```
.col1
  = yield :sub_nav
.col2
  = yield :main
```

Here's the solution...

I refactored the controller method into a application helper

```
  def is_pjax?
    request.xhr? || request.headers['X-PJAX'] ? true : false
  end
```

Then I modified the application view to not render various elements like header, footer, javascripts, css, etc

```
= render :partial => '/shared/footer' unless is_pjax?
```

Now the .pjax requests will render the page and template (left column, main, etc) BUT not the existing elements which are already loaded.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Why didn't your app return anything in the http body? Wouldn't it just return the template?